# Did Goswami Tulsidas preach Harihar bhed or Hari Har abhed?

Tags: ramayana, tulasi

We all have come across Padas of Ramcharitmanas like hari har ninda sune jo kana, sapne na suhahi etc. But all of the verses talk about how hari and hari are both required to be included in bhakti. However, did Tulasidas preach Hari Har abhed?

Comment: To be honest he doesn’t preach either of them.

Comment: @Archit but he clearly in Mangalacharan mentions 'brahmaadi devata' are under the control of Shri Rama. So if that aadi includes Rudra also so doesn't that mean he's under the control of Ram would be different from Rama?

Comment: Yes. Anyway besides that, He just talks about God’s leelas. He just talks about who’s the ultimate aim of all the shastras. He doesn’t preach anything to anyone (means he hasn’t written any commentary to specifically say Hari Hara are the same. He hasn’t written commentary/ preaching to his disciples to say Hari hara are different). He’s above all this discussion. Though there are some chaupais yet personally I’d say he per say doesn’t preach anything and better to leave Tulsidasji out of this discussion.